# wordpress looping through posts in custom php page

Tags: php, wordpress, posts, custom-pages

I trying to loop through posts in a custom php page but no matter what I do, no posts are found
here is the code I wrote in my-custom-page.php

```
<?php 
require_once("/wp-load.php");
get_header();?>
<div id="blog">
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
 <?php echo"anything"; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: I am not referencing this page in any other page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should require wp-load.php via the full path to this file.

Hardcoded example:

```
require_once("user/home/public-html/wordpress/wp-load.php");
```

Softcoded example (suposing your file is in the same directory as WordPress):

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/wp-load.php");
```

You have also to query the posts before you display them. So, you need to add this line to your code:

```
query_posts('post_type=post');
```

The query arguments may vary depending on what you want to display. Some of them are the member variables of the WP_Post class. Go to https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post for reference.

Here you have a re-writing of your code that displays the titles of the 30 latest posts published:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/wp-load.php");
query_posts('post_type=post&showposts=30');
get_header();?>
<div id="blog">
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
         the_title();
         echo '<br />';
   endwhile;
else :
    echo 'Sorry, no posts found.';
endif;?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: thank you for your full and clear explanation, however the result is:
sorry no posts found

Comment: @Exact Precisions - I understand that the author of this question is not on the search for a custom page template, but for a custom php page to be called from outside WordPress.

Comment: As you've got the 'Sorry, no posts found' response, this means your query is running well but no posts are retrieved. So check if there are any posts of the type 'post' in the database. Try changing to `post-type='page'` to see if you find a positive result. And be sure that the required 'wp-load.php' file path leads to the very WordPress instalation to which those posts are connected.

Comment: I mean `post_type='page'` (with underscore, not hyphen). Sorry.

Comment: I surely have posts stored in database
the thing is when I run this code in edit.php it works well but when I run it in a custom php page I always get "sorry no posts found"

Comment: your comment was the solution, looks like a parameter must be passed to this method

Answer (score 0):

wp_count_posts :
@return object Number of posts for each status.

you're trying to echo an object which ends in a fatal error. Furthermore if you want to see all posts the_post is not right. Look for it at the function reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post. I would do it other (google smth like "get all posts").

Comment: thank you for your answer, I edited the code, this code is not typing anything either

Answer (score 0):

if you will use the code inside your theme 
use the same code of Mr.Carlos but with out dir

```
require_once("/wp-load.php");
```